# How can I flatten a hardwood floor in preparation for new flooring over it?

Tags: subfloor, hardwood, self-leveling-concrete, engineered-flooring, leveling

I have a second floor with T/G hardwood flooring that is in very bad shape. I have decided the easiest solution for me is to float new engineered hardwood over top of the old hardwood. There is no existing subfloor under the hardwood, so removal of the old flooring is not really an option for me. My other problem is that the floor is very uneven, over an inch out of flat over a 5 foot span in some areas. This is far outside the recommended flatness for installing a floating floor, but I am also not sure how I can remedy this given that I assume pouring leveler over hardwood is a very bad idea. The only solution I came up with was to cut out pieces of cork underlayment and glue them down to the low spots in the floor while trying to keep the surface as in-plane as possible with the rest of the existing floor. Is there a better solution for this problem? I have also seen some guys that just ignore the recommended flatness criteria and install right over a wavy floor, but I'm a little worried about doing this given how bad my floors are.

Comment: What is the cause of the waviness?

Comment: From redoing a bathroom, where I actually did go ahead and remove the floor entirely and put in a subfloor, I was able to see that someone installed steel flitches across several floor joists sometime in the past. These are 2x10 joists that span almost 16 feet, which is way to long. So, either some of these joists cracked or just sagged over time. As far I can tell everything is properly shored up now, but the floor itself still has these low spots.

Comment: Well, the only "better" solution is to remove the hardwood, sister the joists to level things, and lay new subfloor. Your cork idea will leave you with a lumpy mess that's even less suitable for your new flooring. What makes you say you can't use self-leveler?

Comment: Yes, removing the entire flooring was my original plan, but the amount of work this will be is too daunting. It was fine for a single bathroom, but there are four bedrooms and hall that I want to cover now.

Comment: I would think leveling compound would crack due to movement in the wood floor, causing a crunchy sound on down the road. Maybe I am wrong to think this though.

Comment: You're probably right, but for all I know someone makes a semi-flexible material that would handle that situation. I'd look into that.

Comment: Another option is sanding down the old flooring, it is a waste anyway.

Comment: Sanding won't work due to how out of flat it is (as much as an inch over a 5 foot span).

Comment: @isherwood is correct. The right way to fix it is to sister up new joists to make a level surface and lay new sub-flooring then your new floor on top. All in all it would be the best way to get rid of the problem once and for all.

Comment: I do fully agree with you. Unfortunately, this will simply be too invasive of a project with my family living in the house and me doing the work myself. So, the float floor is my next best option.

Comment: plywood or strips of pine might be better than cork, but one inch is a huge dip: something really bad could be happening under there.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above, there was obviously a serious issue with the floor joists in the past, but from what I can tell this has been remedied. About 4 of the floor joists now have thick steel flitches bolted to both faces. So, I do think the underlying structural problem has been corrected, even though the overal sag still exists.